# Pandoc LaTeX to Word -citation-style doesn't change

Tags: bibliographies, pandoc, latex-to-word

I just discovered Pandoc and I am trying to use it to convert a `doc.tex` into a `doc.docx` but I facing some difficulties with the bibliography convertion.
I write in the powershell cmd:

```
pandoc -s MyFile.tex  --bibliography=MyRefs.bib 
--csl=american-sociological-review.csl -o MyFile.doc
```

`MyFile.tex`, `MyRefs.bib` and the `asr.csl` are in the same folder.
But whatever `file.csl` I insert, the result at the end in the `MyFile.docx` is the same chicago style with references in the body of my core text...

I am using TexLive 2015 (I know I need an update which I will do right after my deadline...) on Windows 10

Here is the code of my LaTeX document:

```
\documentclass[french]{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}                     

\usepackage{lmodern}

\usepackage[backend=biber,style=verbose-trad1, ibidtracker=context]
{biblatex}

\renewcommand{\mkibid}[1]{\emph{#1}}

\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[perpage]{footmisc}

\addbibresource{thesegain2017.bib}

\usepackage[english,francais]{babel}

\begin{document}

Il est important de souligner que ces mécanismes n'ont pas de 
finalité\autocite[Voir][p. 112 à 115]
{bourdieu2011champ}.

\printbibliography 

\end{document}
```

I can't find out what is going wrong.
Thank you for your help !

Comment: Are you using  `pandoc-citeproc`? Try: `pandoc -s --bibliography MyRefs.bib --filter pandoc-citeproc --csl american-sociological-review.csl MyFile.tex -o MyFile.docx`

Comment: Well I get a document modified regarding the citation-style but its written in the powershel command: (permission denied) and  comments --like those with the pages references-- are still missing

Comment: Maybe you should post some code. A [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) would be nice.

Comment: Also: powershell problems, like insufficient permissions, are off topic on TeX.SX and should be asked on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com)

Comment: There are no citations in your MWE

Comment: True. Sorry... @DG'

Comment: Ok, now we need `thesegain2017.bib` with the entry for `bourdieu2011champ` . . .

Comment: I am sorry these things are complicated for me. I am a social scientist I have no computer literacy. . .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's take the following LaTeX document:

**MyFile.tex**

```
\documentclass[french]{article}
\usepackage[english,francais]{babel}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}                     
\usepackage{lmodern}

\usepackage[backend=biber,style=verbose-trad1, ibidtracker=context]
{biblatex}
\addbibresource{MyRefs.bib}

\begin{document}

Il est important de souligner que ces mécanismes n'ont pas de 
finalité \autocite[Voir][p. 112 à 115]{Bourdieu89}.

\printbibliography 

\end{document}
```

and a matching biblatex file:

**MyRefs.bib**

```
@book{Bourdieu89, 
  address   = {Paris}, 
  author    = {Bourdieu, Pierre}, 
  publisher = {Les Editions de Minuit}, 
  title     = {La noblesse d'État}, 
  subtitle  = {Grandes écoles et esprit de corps}, 
  year      = {1989}, 
}
```

[image]
[image]

Since pandoc doesn't know how to name the reference section, you have to set the metadata `reference-section-title` accordingly:

```
pandoc -s --bibliography MyRefs.bib --filter pandoc-citeproc --csl american-sociological-review.csl --biblatex MyFile.tex -M reference-section-title=Références -o MyFile.docx
```

[image]

Comment: `--filter pandoc-citeproc` is deprecated. Use `--citeproc` instead